# Python threads repeating values

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am trying to write  a python SHA512 brute forcer.

I use a Queue to store the values in the wordlist and then compare them against the encrypted hash.

The problem is that, instead of the values being popped out of the Queue, they are reused by other threads. So basically, instead of having the whole work split between threads to make things faster, I got several threads doing the exact same thing. How can I fix this?

I want something like this: https://github.com/WillPennell/Python/blob/master/Black-Hat-Python/BHP-Code/Chapter5/content_bruter.py#L20

```
import threading
import thread
import Queue
import os,sys
import crypt
import codecs
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import argparse
today = datetime.today()
resume = None
threads = 5



def build_wordlist(wordlist_file):

    fd = open(wordlist_file,"rb")
    raw_words = fd.readlines()
    fd.close()

    found_resume = False
    words        = Queue.Queue()

    for word in raw_words:

        word = word.rstrip()

        if resume is not None:

            if found_resume:
                words.put(word)
            else:
                if word == resume:
                    found_resume = True
                    print "Resuming wordlist from: %s" % resume

        else:
            words.put(word)

    return words


def testPass(cryptPass,user):

    word_queue     =       build_wordlist('test.txt')


    while not word_queue.empty():
        attempt = word_queue.get()
        ctype = cryptPass.split("$")[1]
        if ctype == '6':
            print "[+] Hash type SHA-512 detected ..."
            salt = cryptPass.split("$")[2]
            insalt = "$" + ctype + "$" + salt + "$"
            word    =   attempt
            cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word,insalt)
            if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
                time = time = str(datetime.today() - today)
                print "[+] Found password for the user: " + user + " ====> " + word + " Time: "+time+"\n"
                return

    print "Password not found for the user: " + user
    print "Moving on to next user..."
    exit

def main():
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A simple brute force /etc/shadow .')
    parse.add_argument('-f', action='store', dest='path', help='Path to shadow file, example: \'/etc/shadow\'')
    argus=parse.parse_args()
    if argus.path == None:
        parse.print_help()
        exit
    else:
        build_wordlist('test.txt')
        passFile = open (argus.path,'r')
        for line in passFile.readlines():
            line = line.replace("\n","").split(":")
            if  not line[1] in [ 'x' , '*' , '!' ]:
                user = line[0]
                cryptPass = line[1]
                for i in range(threads):
                    t = threading.Thread(target=testPass,args=(cryptPass,user))
                    t.daemon = True
                    t.start()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: I realized there are 2 ways I can do this:
first, I can create a thread for each user, which is not what I want. 
Second, I can split the work of each user through several threads, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this block of code :

```
for i in range(threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=testPass,args=(cryptPass,user))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

And let's describe what this is doing for each thread you start :

1. **create a new `Queue` object from `test.txt` as defined by `build_wordlist`**
2. Process the queue from step 1

It sounds like your desired behavior is to multithread some processing step on a single queue rather than create duplicates of the same queue.  So this means your "testPass" method should probably take in a Queue object.  i.e.

```
q = build_wordlist('test.txt')
for i in range(threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=testPass,args=(q, cryptPass,user))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

and `testPass` should look like :

```
def testPass(queue, cryptPass, user):

    word_queue = queue
    ... stuff ...
```